# how to implement a custom menu UI in xaml

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

Here is the thing , i want to implement a user interface like this blueprint below, i am newbie to xaml , can anyone teach me in detail,i will be grateful

[image: a user menu with buttons and lixbox,viewscroll and so on,i am not clear what and how to use these controlls,especially the style and template]

i want to know the architecture, every control that will be used, and the style and template that will implement this UI. Thanks in advance~~ :)

Comment: Sorry but this is not a teaching platform. You have to go through some tutorials and try to implement something by your own. This is a typical learning-curve that everyone(ok maybe not everyone) goes through.

Comment: yeah,sure,but i have some basics on XAML,my problem is not capable of  implementing complex UI.Thanks for your warning ：）

Comment: Anyway, there comes the time where you have to face the complex stuff also. You just can't relax on the simple stuff.

Comment: you are right,i will keep hard working on it,Thanks dude :)

Comment: 'Dude'. I don't whats wrong with you guys...

Comment: hah,sorry,i mean my friend...

Answer (score 0):

There is a fantastic series on developing UWP apps using XAML

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-10-development-for-absolute-beginners

I suggest you start there, there are plenty of episodes that slowly go through all the concepts of xaml. Most of the episodes are just a few minutes long. It should help you get started.

Comment: Thanks for your advice,i have already learned some basics on XAML,i just do not have some clue on how to group these controls,and how to use complex style and template.